# Android printer aligment not correct

Tags: android, printing

My application have the facility to take print using Bluetooth ,It work fine, My problem is the print is not  alined for all device like 3 inch printer and etc. Can i able to fix this using code. For the last few-days i am searching for a permanent solution. If any one having ticks please share

Comment: Try to describe what you have tried. How do you search, what do you found, how does it work and why it is not suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by creating different alignment for the different printers